# How do I perform variable assignment with a loop, and break?

Tags: ruby

Here is the logic:

```
y = 'var to check for'

some_var = some_loop.each do |x|
  x if x == y
  break if x
end
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Something like

```
x && break if x == y
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `x if x == y` *supposed* to do? Better would start with "understandable", maybe even using [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) or whatnot. (But no, Enumerable#each *cannot* be terminated early except for raising an Exception - `break` applies only the loop constructs such as `for` or `while`.)

Comment: To add more clarity.. I am checking for a value in a list. If that value exists, I want to assign it to the variable and break out of the loop so I don't check other values.

Comment: Then use [`Enumerable#first`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-first): `found = arr.first {|x| x == y}; if !found.nil? ..`

Comment: That works perfect.. If you can put this as an answer I can mark this and upvote it.. Thank you so much.. !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is to use `include?`.  eg:

```
found = (array_expression).include? {|x| x == search_value}
```

It's possible to also use `each` and break out on the first matched value, but the C implementation of `include?` is faster than a ruby script with `each`.

Here is a test program, comparing the performance of invoking `include?` on a very large array vs. invoking `each` on the same array with the same argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
require 'benchmark'

def f_include a, b
  b if a.include?(b)
end

def f_each_break a, b
  a.each {|x| return b if x == b }
  nil
end

# gen large array of random numbers
a = (1..100000).map{|x| rand 1000000}

# now select 1000 random numbers in the set
nums = (1..1000).map{|x| a[rand a.size]}

# now, check the time for f1 vs. f2
r1 = r2 = nil

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report('incl') { r1 = nums.map {|n| f_include    a,n} }
  bm.report('each') { r2 = nums.map {|n| f_each_break a,n} }
end
if r1.size != r2.size || r1 != r2
  puts "results differ"
  puts "r1.size = #{r1.size}"
  puts "r2.size = #{r2.size}"
  exceptions = (0..r1.size).select {|x| x if r1[x] != r2[x]}.compact
  puts "There were #{exceptions.size} exceptions"
else
  puts "results ok"
end

exit
```

Here is the output from the test:

```
$ ./test-find.rb
       user     system      total        real
incl  5.150000   0.090000   5.240000 (  7.410580)
each  7.400000   0.140000   7.540000 (  9.269962)
results ok
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for taking the time to enlighten. Good stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
some_var = (some_loop.include? y ? y : nil)
```

Comment: @user2864740 I'm confused. You didn't add anything to my answer.

Comment: I formatted the code-block - there has to be a blank line above it for it to be rendered as such. Hit refresh.